# Copying a 1D array to a row of 2D array using memcpy

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to copy a 1D array to a particular row of a 2D array using memcpy. I tried compiling the below code on  [OnlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) ,but its printing garbage value and then giving segmentation fault.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
     int arr1[5] = {34, 45, 89,123,56};
     int arr2[2][5];
     memcpy(arr2[0],arr1,sizeof(arr2[0]));
     // arr1[5] = {89,45,90,15,23};
     memcpy(arr2[1],arr1,sizeof(arr2[1]));

     for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
        for(int j=0;i<5;j++) {
            printf("%d ",arr2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain what will be correct way to code this using memcpy?

Comment: In the second `for`, you've got `i<5` instead of `j<5`, so loop never ends

Comment: @DenisSheremet Thanks so much its working now. I should have been more careful before posting the question here.

Comment: Just proves you are *human* and not some automated *bot*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the condition in the inner loop (`i<5`).

Here’s a fix (with hardcodings removed).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
     int arr1[] = {34, 45, 89, 123, 56};
     int arr2[2][sizeof arr1 / sizeof *arr1];
     memcpy(arr2[0], arr1, sizeof arr1);
     memcpy(arr2[1], arr1, sizeof arr1);

     for (int i = 0; i < sizeof arr2 / sizeof *arr2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof arr2[i] / sizeof *arr2[i]; j++) {
            printf("%d ", arr2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whoops. I copy-pasted the wrong version. Thanks for noticing. I’ve edited it.